# How can I view internet/network usage for a single session?

Tags: networking, internet

I would like to view the internet usage for a single session, for example I connect to the WiFi at my local library which has a 200MB limit.
Is it possible to connect and start tracking the data use - starting from zero and simply keep tracking until I reset or clear the history?

I have looked into

- Ubuntu's pre-installed `system monitor` - this seems to track the total historical data for some given period
- vnstat - same problem - by default -it aggregates historical data - e.g. how much data has already been used  in sessions that have been and gone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try a workaround using `vnstat`

`man vnstat`

```
-l, --live mode
              Display current transfer rate for the selected interface in real
              time until interrupted. Statistics will be shown after interrup‐
              tion if the runtime was more than 10 seconds. An  optional  mode
              parameter  can be used to select between the displaying of pack‐
              ets per second (mode 0) and transfer counters  (mode  1)  during
              execution.  --style can also be used to affect the layout of the
              output.
```

So you can use the live mode, this require manual starting and closing so start monitoring when start your session by running the command `vnstat -l` and close it by (ctrl+c) when  you end your session.

```
$ vnstat -l

Monitoring eth0...    (press CTRL-C to stop)

   rx:        0 kbit/s     1 p/s          tx:        0 kbit/s     0 p/s^C


 eth0  /  traffic statistics

                           rx         |       tx
--------------------------------------+------------------
  bytes                      246 KiB  |         232 KiB
--------------------------------------+------------------
          max             624 kbit/s  |      620 kbit/s
      average           59.64 kbit/s  |    56.24 kbit/s
          min               0 kbit/s  |        0 kbit/s
--------------------------------------+------------------
  packets                        745  |             595
--------------------------------------+------------------
          max                121 p/s  |          86 p/s
      average                 22 p/s  |          18 p/s
          min                  1 p/s  |           0 p/s
--------------------------------------+------------------
  time                    33 seconds
```

If you want to see the result in live mode use the mode 1

```
$ vnstat -l 1

Monitoring eth0...    (press CTRL-C to stop)

   rx:      4 kbit/s   48 KiB             tx:     28 kbit/s   270 KiB
```

AS seen above received from starting the command is 48K running 4K/s while the transmitting is 270K running 28K/s

I think this is what do you want exactly

#### Another possible solution

[Bitmeter OS](http://codebox.org.uk/pages/bitmeterOs)

> BitMeter OS is a free, open-source, bandwidth monitor that works on
>   Windows, Linux and Mac OSX. BitMeter OS keeps track of how much you
>   use your internet/network connection, and allows you to view this
>   information either via a web browser, or by using the command line
>   tools.

Download your version from [here](http://codebox.org.uk/pages/bitmeteros/downloads).

Now you can easily install it using

```
sudo dpkg -i bitmeter*.deb
```

Once it's installed locate your browser to  http://localhost:2605/

[image]

Now to do the trick for your needs  Go to Alert tab.

[image]

create a new Alert specifying the amount of data for Internet and time for your sessions. take a look for.

Comment: thanks, I have just been testing your  `vnstat` solution. This is interesting, I had to use `vnstat -l -i wlan0` to get it to work on a Wi-Fi interface.  the ongoing "realtime" reporting is on the transfer rate. This means the only way you can  check how much data is used is to `ctrl + c` cancel the process at which point the usage total get zeroed. So to get the total used in the session you would have to probably start a shell - name it "MB counter" and keep track of the totals from every time you checked `vnstat`.

Comment: You can view the consumption on real time, you don't need to kill the process

Comment: Try it, you'll get your consumption on real time

Comment: take a look : http://askubuntu.com/tour

Comment: Thanks, your answer says *An  optional  mode
              parameter  can be used to select between the displaying of pack‐
              ets per second (mode 0) and transfer counters  (mode  1)  during
              execution.* does I need to enable this `mode 1` to get the usage counter ? This answer is very close to a usable solution. If no other answers I would mark it as accepted, at the moment I just cant get the usage numbers to report

Comment: I'll update my answer

Comment: works perfect thanks. On a side note, when you see your data consumption in real time - its amazing how much MB you burn through just loading a few web pages!

Comment: @user4668401 you are welcome